# Is there any ready made pattern or library to implement Memento pattern for ones classes instead of reinventing the wheel?

Tags: c++, c++11, memento

I have classes like this:

```
class MyClass{
    int myField1;
    int myField2;

    MyMemento* getMemento(){
        auto m = new MyMemento();
        m->myField1 = myField1;
        m->myField2 = myField2;
    }

    void restore(MyMemento* m){
        myField1 = m->myField1;
        myField2 = m->myField2;
    }
}

class MyMemento{
public:
    int myField1;
    int myField2;
}
```

I have many classes like MyClass, each with their own unique member variables. But the pattern of the functions for creating / restoring the memento is the same, and the actual memento object simply contains variables matching each class.

This seems very tedious to implement for each class, so was wondering if there is some readymade class, library or pattern I can use to implement this instead ?

Comment: You could extract the variables into a common `Storage` struct which both the memento and the original class use. Might be a valid case for private or protected inheritance if you want to keep the current syntax.

Comment: That's a good idea. But I guess I would need to create a Storage struct for each class type.

Comment: Yeah, but you have to write the fields somewhere anyway, there is no code generation in C++ sadly.

Comment: @Quimby - Maybe this is a dumb question - but why wouldn't I just copy the instance of the class itself, and store it somewhere ? (assuming it has no pointers etc). Then making a copy is just one line....

Comment: Google Protobuf (other libraries exist) the keyword you are looking for is "serialisation".

Comment: @RahulIyer You definitely can, that's even better than `Storage`, I assumed there was some reason why there is a separate `Memento` class.

Comment: @Quimby Not entirely sure. I was just trying to implement memento based on a book I was reading. I guess the point of the object is maybe for compactness, or if some processing is required when restoring an object, or if there are some pointers in use somewhere. I'm still trying to understand the best way.

Comment: @RahulIyer I don't have much experience with that pattern, but the memento object is there to restore a certain version of the original, how is it done can differ. It could e.g. be a filename that loads the contents from some backup file on disk. Hence the reason for two types.

Comment: @Quimby makes sense.